# How to stop TIDYCom from deleting opening tags that don't have closing tags tags during cleanup

Tags: vb.net, tidy, htmltidy

TidyCom removes unclosed tags during cleanup. For example, the `<p>` tag with missing closing is wiped off when compared with source file.

How can this be retained, instead? Here is my code:

```
 Dim tid As New TidyObject()

    tid.Options.Doctype = "strict"
    tid.Options.OutputXml = True
    tid.Options.AddXmlDecl = True
    tid.Options.Clean = False
    tid.Options.DropEmptyParas = True
    tid.Options.DropFontTags = False
    tid.Options.CharEncoding = CharEncoding.utf8
    tid.Options.QuoteAmpersand = True
    tid.Options.QuoteMarks = False
    tid.Options.QuoteNbsp = True
    tid.Options.TidyMark = False
    tid.Options.LogicalEmphasis = True
    tid.Options.BreakBeforeBr = False
    tid.Options.FixBackslash = True
    tid.Options.FixBadComments = True
    tid.Options.Wrap = True
    tid.Options.UppercaseAttributes = False
    tid.Options.UppercaseTags = False
    tid.Options.Indent = True
    tid.Options.IndentSpaces = 4
    tid.Options.IndentAttributes = True
    tid.Options.Word2000 = False
```

Comment: This question is unclear; it sounds like Tidy is doing exactly what it is designed to do: remove bad HTML. If you don't want it to delete unclosed opening `p` tags, close them?

Answer (score 1):

You can have reference at this link http://w3c.github.io/tidy-html5/quickref.html#drop-empty-paras
as you have set it to true, this might be causing problem.